# Sending a message to a member (discord.js)

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, member, sharding

How can I send a message to a member who is in another shard than me?

I tried `let member= await client.shard.fetchClientValues('users.cache.get("args[0]")')` but didn't work.

Comment: how do you plan to identify this member?

Comment: Hi and Welcome to StackOverFlow, Please provide more detail about the problem by sharing a part of the codes and details about them. So people can answer your question faster.

Comment: I plan to identify him by his id, which will be in args [0].

Answer (score 0):

If you can get their ID try
`client.users.cache.get(id).send(message)`

Comment: inside the client.shard.fetchClientValues?

Comment: yea, it should look trough all the shards

Comment: make sure you are not putting args[0] in "", if you do it will look for args[0] and not actually the ID

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that you have the id stored in a variable named `userID`, then you could proceed this way :

```js
client.shard.broadcastEval(`
    const user = client.users.cache.get("${userID}");
    if (user) user.send("Your Message");
`);
```

But this may send the message multiple times if the user is found on multiple shards, so make sure to keep this in your mind ;)